# DisplayPort to HDMI Adapter doesn't play audio on Samsung TV

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, hdmi, television, video-adapter

I can't make my **MacBook Pro mid 2009** play audio on my Samsung LCD TV. I am aware that only recents MacBook Pro have audio out through the Mini DisplayPort and mine doesn't have it. This is why I bought [an adapter that includes digital audio](http://www.newertech.com/products/tcblmdphdmid.php).

I can see the video on the TV but can't hear anything, the sound is still going out of my laptop.

I tried to go in "**System Preferences > Audio > Output**" but I can only see "Internal Speakers" from here.

Do you have any idea what did I miss here?
Thanks.

Comment: I finally managed to make it work... I had to reboot my computer, weird. Thanks anyway for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without resorting to AirPort or other networked setups, your only option is probably to just use a 3.5mm jack from your headphone port, which would unfortunately only give you stereo audio.

Comment: glad you got it to work :)